# creating a new line on a textbox in tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, textbox

I have imported a list of names from a csv file and want to print each name a new line, how would i go about this as the program i have wrote prints it all on one line?

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
master=Tk()

file=open('Book1.csv')
qwerty=csv.reader(file)

people=[]
for column in qwerty:
     people.append(column[0:7])

namelbl=Label(text='Name').grid(column=1,row=1)
namebox=Text(master,width=10)
namebox.grid(column=1,row=2)
namesList = [x[0] for x in people]
for names in sorted(namesList):
   namebox.insert(END, names)
   print(names)

master.mainloop()
```

apology's about the poor coding i'm new.
Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have just to add `\n` :

```
namebox.insert(END, names + '\n')
```